# where do i edit and run the app in react-native for android

Tags: android, react-native

I am new to react-native, i have installed and well setup for my ubuntu system to react-native but having confusion about how to run and debug the app like doing in android studio. Let me know any specific editor, IDE to debug and run the app for both android and ios

Answer (score 0):

You run the app with

```
$ react-native run-android
```

To access the logs run log-android in another terminal.

```
$ react-native log-android
```

Next you can enable remote debugging in the debug menu <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (that's <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on macOS and shaking the device on physical device). If you use redux, use [Remote Redux DevTools](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/remote-redux-devtools).

As for an IDE, you might try out GitHub's [Atom](https://atom.io/) with Facebook's [Nuclide](https://nuclide.io/) package.

Comment: Thanks @viktor Sec for your reply. Then how do i check my design files fit into mobile screen like xml layouts view in android studio? Is there any possibilities in atom Editor?

Comment: I don't know what you mean with _design files_. I just compose the screen, style it and run it in the simulator.

Comment: actually how should i design for my app there is some editor to check the alignment of views for different screen for android

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by design. Sketching wireframes? Drawing mockups? Building prototypes? You can use the same tools you would use for standard web design, I guess.

What's bad about writing the component, styling it and trying it in the simulator as I suggested previously? You can try out all the different screen sizes you want in the simulator.